# Running JModelica in PyCharm - running a .bat file before the PyCharm interpreter to setup the environment

Tags: pycharm, jmodelica

I do most of my development work in PyCharm and would like to do the same with JModelica. I understand that the `setenv.bat` needs to be run before the interpreter is opened, so that the interpreter knows where to locate the JModelica Python Libraries such as `pymodelica`. [See this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051857/setting-up-jupyter-notebook-for-jmodelica). But how can this be achieved within PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a startPyCharm.bat e.g.

```
call C:\JModelica.org-SDK-1.12\setenv.bat
start C:\....\pycharm.exe
```

(similarly to C:\JModelica.org-SDK-1.12\Python.bat)

Comment: This worked. So does this keep setenv.bat opened in the background so that whenever a new interpreter is opened in PyCharm it contains the same environment?